# How to Integrate Arc Lengths using python, numpy, and scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, automatic-ref-counting, ellipse

On another [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433094/how-to-determine-the-arc-length-of-ellipse), I saw someone manage to integrate the length of a arc using mathematica.They wrote:

```
In[1]:= ArcTan[3.05*Tan[5Pi/18]/2.23]
Out[1]= 1.02051
In[2]:= x=3.05 Cos[t];
In[3]:= y=2.23 Sin[t];
In[4]:= NIntegrate[Sqrt[D[x,t]^2+D[y,t]^2],{t,0,1.02051}]
Out[4]= 2.53143
```

How exactly could this be transferred to python using the imports of numpy and scipy? In particular, I am stuck on line 4 in his code with the "NIntegrate" function. Thanks for the help!

Also, if I already have the arc length and the vertical axis length, how would I be able to reverse the program to spit out the original paremeters from the known values? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge `scipy` cannot perform symbolic computations (such as symbolic differentiation). You may want to have a look at http://www.sympy.org for a symbolic computation package. Therefore, in the example below, I compute derivatives analytically (the `Dx(t)` and `Dy(t)` functions).

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Dx = lambda t: -3.05 * np.sin(t)
>>> Dy = lambda t: 2.23 * np.cos(t)
>>> quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, 1.02051)
(2.531432761012828, 2.810454936566873e-14)
```

## EDIT: Second part of the question - inverting the problem

From the fact that you know the value of the integral (arc) you can now solve for *one* of the parameters that determine the arc (semi-axes, angle, etc.) Let's assume you want to solve for the angle. Then you can use one of the non-linear solvers in [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html), to revert the equation `quad(theta) - arcval == 0`. You can do it like this:

```
>>> from scipy.integrate import quad
>>> from scipy.optimize import broyden1
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = 3.05
>>> b = 2.23
>>> Dx = lambda t: -a * np.sin(t)
>>> Dy = lambda t: b * np.cos(t)
>>> arc = lambda theta: quad(lambda t: np.sqrt(Dx(t)**2 + Dy(t)**2), 0, np.arctan((a / b) * np.tan(np.deg2rad(theta))))[0]
>>> invert = lambda arcval: float(broyden1(lambda x: arc(x) - arcval, np.rad2deg(arcval / np.sqrt((a**2 + b**2) / 2.0))))
```

Then:

```
>>> arc(50)
2.531419526553662
>>> invert(arc(50))
50.000031008458365
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I'm sorry, but I just have one quick question about the quad function at the end. If I already have the arc length of 2.5314327, how would I be able to reverse that function in code? Thanks!

Comment: @FairlyFactual What do you mean by "reversing"? This is a definite integral. I would guess that you want to solve the equation `quad(of something) == 2.53...`. The question is: what do you want to solve for?

Comment: @FairlyFactual I added my attempt to solve your "reverse problem" the way I understood it to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer a pure numerical approach, you could use the following barebones solution. This worked well for me given that I had two input `numpy.ndarray`s, `x` and `y` with no functional form available.

```py
import numpy as np

def arclength(x, y, a, b):
    """
    Computes the arclength of the given curve
    defined by (x0, y0), (x1, y1) ... (xn, yn)
    over the provided bounds, `a` and `b`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: numpy.ndarray
        The array of x values

    y: numpy.ndarray
        The array of y values corresponding to each value of x

    a: int
        The lower limit to integrate from

    b: int
        The upper limit to integrate to

    Returns
    -------
    numpy.float64
        The arclength of the curve

    """
    bounds = (x >= a) & (y <= b)

    return np.trapz(
        np.sqrt(
            1 + np.gradient(y[bounds], x[bounds])
        ) ** 2),
        x[bounds]
    )
```

Note: I spaced the return variables out that way just to make it more readable and clear to understand the operations taking place.

As an aside, recall that the arc-length of a curve is given by:

[image: Arc-length Equation]

Comment: This is great, thank you! In my opinion (for my application), much better than the Symbolic Sympy method.